# How to plot a line between 2 points

Tags: plot, line, point, pine-script

i use this script to find highs and lows: https://www.tradingview.com/script/eH0vkSBy-Swing-Highs-and-Lows/. I want to plot a line between two last points(2 swing highs or 2 swing lows) so that in the future, if price close above/under line i get an entry signal. One more nuance - i use renko bars. How i can do this?
Something like that:

```
strategy(title='My first strategy')
//code provided in the link
prhigh=valuewhen(isSwingHigh,high,0)
l = line.new(barindex, prhigh, barindex[1], prhigh[1], width = 4)// I don't know how to get barindex
alertcondition(crossover(l,close), 'Swing High', 'New SwingHigh')
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.tradingview.com/script/mpeEgn5J-Trendlines-JD/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous scripts that aim to draw lines from swing high's swing low's.

https://www.tradingview.com/script/CtjX82Hp-Extrapolated-Pivot-Connector-Lets-Make-Support-And-Resistances/

However remember that you can't create alerts involving a series interacting with a line object, as this one don't have numerical values.

One option to get a line connecting two values without using `line.new` is to use `plot(isSwingHigh ? close : na)`, when you plot a series containing na values `plot` will connect the two last non na values with a line.